# Pandas Multiplication over different dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have below dataframes (`df1` and `df2`) in `pandas`. What I want to achieve is to multiply `df1` with `df2` matching column header and create `df3`. Expected results are,

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([{'A':2,'B':2.2,'C':20},
                    {'A':2.5,'B':2.8,'C':24},
                    {'A':3.0,'B':2.8,'C':24.8}])
```

I've tried to use `df3 = df1.mul(df2,axis=1)` but it is not working. It produced a lot of `NaN` and give extra 2 columns. Can anyone share some hints?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'A':20,'B':22,'C':25},
                    {'A':25,'B':28,'C':30},
                    {'A':30,'B':28,'C':31}])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'X':'A','Y':0.1},
                    {'X':'B','Y':0.1},
                    {'X':'C','Y':0.8}])
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you posted the expected result

Comment: Sorry just edited it with expected result. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed `df2` to `s2` -- is this what you're looking for?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'A':20,'B':22,'C':25},
                    {'A':25,'B':28,'C':30},
                    {'A':30,'B':28,'C':31}])

s2 = pd.Series(data=[0.1, 0.1, 0.8],
               index=['A', 'B', 'C'])

df1.mul(s2)
```

The result is:

```
    A   B   C
0   2.0 2.2 20.0
1   2.5 2.8 24.0
2   3.0 2.8 24.8
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I want to achieve. Thx.

Comment: Just a question, with your method on s2, how do I pass in the data automatically from column Y of df2 instead of manually key in the the data 0.1,0.1,0.8. I tried iloc but not working.

Comment: `s2 = df2.set_index('X').squeeze()` -- squeeze() converts the one-column data frame to a pandas series.

Answer (score 1):

Get the columns to align on the index, multiply, and unstack to get back your result

```
df1.stack().mul(df2.set_index("X").Y, level=-1).unstack()

     A   B   C
0   2.0 2.2 20.0
1   2.5 2.8 24.0
2   3.0 2.8 24.8
```

Note : This works for more rows (50 as you mentioned in the comments)

Comment: My actual df1 have 50 rows and tried your methods and only produced first 5 rows of correct data. The rest are all NaN. Any idea?

Comment: Yes same column A,B,C for df1. Exact match for index X for df2